# get HTML form values and submit to new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Say I have this form in an app where I want a user to check their interests and then have the values added onto the url  . The destination will only accept url variables.

I got as far as getting one value into the url but it stops there. If I run console(log) I see them all.

Am I missing one simple step or is there a better way?

```html
<form id="message"><input type="checkbox" name="movies" value="Movies" id="Movies"><label class="likeButton" for="Movies">Movies</label><br><input type="checkbox" name="news" value="News" id="News"><label class="likeButton" for="News">News</label><br><input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="Sports" id="Sports"><label class="likeButton" for="Sports">Sports</label></form>
<div class="button-center done">
     <a href="#"><p>DONE</p></a>
</div>
```

```js
$('.done').on('click',function(){

    var dataArray = $('#message').serializeArray();
    
    $.each(dataArray, function(i, field){
        var dataObject = field.value + ' ';
        
        window.open('http://url.com?name=test&property=' + dataObject); 
   
    });
    
 });
```

Comment: if you want to loop over all the values and add them to your URL then running window.open _inside_ the loop is likely to be a mistake - trivially we can see that it will open the window in the first iteration of the loop. I would expect you want to move this after the loop. P.S. If you're trying to create a valid querystring, this is the wrong way to go about it. You'd get all the field values within a single "property" parameter on the URL, separated by spaces and without any names (after all, does the receiving page not need to know what each value refers to??)

Comment: P.S. Just noticed you re-create dataObject each time too, not appending to it with more values. So you'd have to change that too so it adds to the variable instead of replacing it. But I'm still fairly sure the format you'll get out is not what the page is going to expect. It's certainly...unconventional, shall we say.

Comment: Looking at what you actually appear to be trying to do, I think there's a much simpler solution anyway - see the answer below.

Comment: makes sense. So if I move the window.open outside I'd need make a variable of the loop then add on?

Comment: Yes. Although there's a shortcut to that already provided by jQuery, as dganenco has noted in their answer. Or, I'm pretty certain you can use my answer and get rid of your jQuery altogether. I don't think what you're doing now is going to get you the right result in any case. Unless you intend for _all_ your values to be submitted as one single "property" parameter? Perhaps you should give us an example of the intended URL.

Comment: Then again I'm not sure dganenco's answer will actually provide a very good solution (see my comment on the answer itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to submit your form data to a new window/tab, then you don't need any JavaScript at all, you can just add an extra "target" attribute to your form tag, to tell it to submit into a new window.

N.B. If `url.com` is not the URL of your page originally, then you can also add an "action" attribute to specify that:

```
<form id="message" target="_blank" action="http://url.com" >...</form>
```

And instead of your hyperlink, have a proper "submit" button. (You can use CSS to make it *look like* a hyperlink, if that's what you'd prefer.)

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Done"/>
```

If you still want to submit the "name" parameter you've hard-coded into your jQuery code, the easiest way to achieve that would be to add a hidden field to the form instead:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="test"/>
```

So in your case, the finished code would look like:

```
<form id="message" target="_blank" action="http://url.com">
  <input type="checkbox" name="movies" value="Movies" id="Movies">
  <label class="likeButton" for="Movies">Movies</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="news" value="News" id="News">
  <label class="likeButton" for="News">News</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="Sports" id="Sports">
  <label class="likeButton" for="Sports">Sports</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="test"/>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Done"/>
</form>
```

Everything else could be removed.

That way if you were to, for example, tick "News" and "Sports" and then submit, the final URL would look something like `http://url.com?news=News&sports=Sports&name=test`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ryzmL1hs/

Answer (score -1):

You can use [jQuery param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) method.

> Description: Create a serialized representation of an array, a plain
>   object, or a jQuery object suitable for use in a URL query string or
>   Ajax request. In case a jQuery object is passed, it should contain
>   input elements with name/value properties.

```
$('.done').on('click', function() {

  var dataArray = $('#message').serializeArray();

  window.open('http://url.com?name=test&property=' + $.param( dataArray ));

});
```

Comment: Out of interest, if someone selected, say, News and Sports, and then clicked done this would generate a URL like `https://www.url.com/?name=test&property=news%3DNews&sports=Sports` (Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/36zdobmy/). This doesn't look very logical. It's inconsistent - the "news" option is held in the "property" parameter (but containing both the name _and_ the value, separated by a space, but the "sports" value is in its own URL parameter, in the more normal way. If the page being targeted is set up to receive the data in this inconsistent way I'd be a bit surprised.

Comment: After more consideration @ADsyon html only solution would work better for my needs.